# Is there a way to not show your most recent employer/title, while keeping it on your CV?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Most of my career I was not what I was at my most recent job, and I did not find it to be a good fit.  I don't want that to be the first thing an employer sees, because they definitely won't be looking even in the right category of what I'm interested in doing.  Can't it be optional?

Comment: How will you answer when an employer asks "why is there an x year" gap in your recent employment?

Comment: @David `while keeping it on your CV`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we already have this option. If you go to your CV and click "edit" next to your current experience, there's a little "display option" section:

[image: "Display options" -> (checkbox) Prevent this experience from appearing in header]

Click that checkbox and you should be all set!

Comment: I think I even knew that was there at one point.  Forgot all about it.  Thanks!